# How to resolve PulseAudio connection test failed: Failed to connect to pulseaudio server?

Tags: python, debian, dbus, pulseaudio

Multiple days now I have been trying to setup a python service that runs on debian and streams music via bluetooth. The bluetooth part works fine. I am using `dbus`. The problem comes with the `pulsectl` pulse audio service running on the debian computer.  The error is below. It keeps telling that it cannot find the `/run/user/1001/pulse` directory but when I do `ls` it is already there.

```
:Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1001/pulse): No such file or directoryNov 28 14:32:59 triton python3[550]: ERROR app.root - PulseAudio connection test failed: Failed to connect to pulseaudio serverNov 28 14:32:59 triton python3[550]: ERROR app.root - Cannot connect to PulseAudio server. Exiting...
```

I have some logic to first check if `pulsectl` is connected or not and this is where it breaks:

```
def test_pulseaudio_connection():
    try:
        with pulsectl.Pulse("test-connection") as pulse:
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"PulseAudio connection test failed: {e}")
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"] = f"/run/user/{os.getuid()}"

    # First, test the PulseAudio connection
    if not test_pulseaudio_connection():
        logging.error("Cannot connect to PulseAudio server. Exiting...")
        exit(1)  # Exits the program if PulseAudio is not running
```

Also I I have setup the systemd service file with passing and environment file there and also choosing user to run this etc because I read that it should not be the root running pulseaudio service.

```
[Service]ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/backend/src/app.py
WorkingDirectory=/opt/backend/src
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001"
Environment="ENVIRONMENT=development"
User=user
Group=audio
Group=root
Restart=always
[Device]
DeviceAllow=/dev/ttyRS232_A rw
[Install]WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have no idea why it keeps showing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I do `ls` it is already there

User runtime directories are not created at boot time – their existence is tied to existence of interactive login session. So it is 'already there' *after you log in,* but it wasn't yet 'already there' when the service started during system boot before you logged in to check.

Use `loginctl enable-linger $USER` to configure systemd to create the user's runtime directory on boot (as well as start that user's personal "systemctl --user" services on boot).

Then, either add an `After=user-runtime-dir@1000.service` dependency to make sure things happen in the correct order, or (preferably) convert your whole service to a "--user" service in ~/.config/systemd/user/.